# Problemas ao salvar imagem

Tags: php

Estou tentando salvar uma imagem que recebo através de form.

Estou utilizando `move_uploaded_file()` para isso.

No momento, meu código está desta maneira:

```
class Image
{
    public function save($image)
    {
        $name = time();
        $destination = "public/img/vehicles/" . $name . ".jpg";
        $result = move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Arquivo que recebo dados do formulário:

```
$image = $_FILE['image'];

$saveImage = new Image();
$destinationImg = $saveImage->save($image);
```

Mas quando vou conferir no diretório, a imagem não está lá.
E o `$resultImg` sempre me retorna `false`.

Comment: Dentro da classe tente chamar assim, `$image['nome_input_html']['tmp_name']`, na dúvida `print_r($image)`

Comment: @rray Continuou do mesmo jeito...

Comment: Ahhh é `$_FILES` ta faltando um `s` ali no código.

Comment: Isso mesmo, rray! Verdade. Mas mesmo assim ainda me retorna false. :(

Comment: E o print_r() retornou o q?

Comment: Eu dei um print_r na váriavel $image, e ele me retornou o seguinte: `[type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpnjYqd1 [error]`

Comment: Pode ser erro de permissão ou de que a pasta não existe etc. Faz assim p pegar o erro, `if(!move_upload(......parametros.....){ print_r(error_get_last());}`

Comment: Não seria move_uploaded_files()? Quando utilizo o `move_upload` ele me retorna call to undefined function

Comment: Isso, haha digitei errado xD

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40035/discussion-between-naldson-and-rray).

Comment: Consegui resolver... Tudo não passou de um erro ali na var `$destination` da classe. Acontece que ela estava em uma subpasta e tinha que ser na verdade `../public/img/`.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro veja se a variável `$imagem` possui um arquivo de upload valido, usando a função `is_uploaded_file ( string $filename )` .

```
class Image
{
    public function save($image)
    {
        var_dump(is_uploaded_file ($image['tmp_name']));

        $name = time();
        $destination = "public/img/vehicles/" . $name . ".jpg";
        $result = move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $destination);
        var_dump($image['error']);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Se a função acima retornar false (há problema com o arquivo de upload), veja os logs do apache (caso você use o apache como servidor) ou use a função `error_get_last()`.